Does every finding in medical statistics need to be validated in an independent dataset?
I am performing a medical statistics analysis about 500 independent variables and 1 dependent variables. The sample size is 1200. The relation between the variables and outcomes are weak (say, diet and disease), so I can only use p values to get the significant related variables with nonzero effect as my findings.
Because the relation is weak and I have another dataset with 300 samples, so I want to use the new dataset as a validation dataset. I found that about half of the significant variables have same trend in the vaidation dataset, but they most have a high p value.
I think this is reasonable because the p value can increase with smaller sample size. But my question is that: are the other significant findings (p < 0.05) in the 1200 samples reliable even not validated in the validation dataset?

Your assertion "I can only use p values to get some significant related variables as my findings" is puzzling: why is that the case?  With so many independent variables you have little prospect of identifying any real relationship with any reliability unless it is extremely strong and unconfounded by the other variables.  Another concept to beware of is "p value can increase with smaller sample size."  That's only assuming there is a nonzero effect!

@whuber That's only assuming there is a nonzero effect!: While I certainly agree with this, I would contend that if data for a variable has been collected, then some effect, however small, is probably there. At the extreme, everything must have an effect. The problem is that for a pvalue of 0.1 found in a small dataset it is not at all guaranteed that in a bigger dataset that pvalue will become smaller and the effect will be in the same direction as initially found and even then the original estimate may be overestimated.

I am assuming that your analysis is done via some form of regression? Can you confirm this? And if so which specific regression are you using? Is the DV continuous or categorical? Can you provide a bit more descriptions? Thanks

@jginestet Thank you for your interest. Actually, the x variables are the serum compounds and the y variables are intelligence score (continuous). I am now performing regression analysis (multiple linear regression) for each independent variable and confounder variables. I think this is a basic and robust way to explore the potential relationship between the variables and outcomes.

As discussed here a 300 patient dataset provides a noisy independent validation.  For what you are trying to do the sample size is tiny.  But the first validation should almost always be a strong internal validation.  You’ll likely find that this test fails and it’s not fruitful to move on to a large  external validation.  You probably need to ask simpler questions, using unsupervised learning (data reduction) in a first phase.

Thank you for your advice and this helpful book! The question I mainly focus here is finding the outcome-related variables. Does it mean that I should perform data reduction first and then a strong internal validation (cross-validation and bootstrapping)? Furthermore, in the cross-validation, do I need to increase the proportion of testing samples, such as 2-fold cross validation? Would you please give me some advice about my analysis?

The chapter I linked to goes into detail about validation procedures.  For your case either use the Efron-Gong “optimism bootstrap” with, say, 300 resamples, or do 100 repeats of 10-fold cross-validation.  A single 10-fold CV or your suggested 2-fold CV will be imprecise, i.e., will change too much if you repeated the process starting with a different random number seed.  And note that “finding outcome-related variables” is not possible in most situations; the data do not contain sufficient information for discerning that.

Thanks again. I have just performed PCA on my discovery data (n=1200) and use AIC to get the optimal 35 PCs. Then I performed multiple linear regression with the 35 PCs with 100 repeats of 10-fold CV, and now the performance in the training and tesing samples are similar, although only 5% R2. I think this is a good internal validation enough. But I have still two questions: 1. Each PCs are composed of all the variables, how to determine the most important variables (it is an omics dataset)? 2. Then is there some ways to validate in my external dataset (300 samples) to support any findings?

Putting it simply, you are overfitting. You can look at your situation this way: you have 1200 observations (which is a rather large sample size), but you have 500 predictors (very large). That is, so to speak, ~2.5 observations per predictor. I am certain that if you tried to regress a single DV based on 3 observations of a single IV, you would think this to be an unreliable regression, and not worthy of publishing (or showing to your boss/colleagues). And I am not even accounting for the fact that you may (should?) have interaction terms, and maybe even higher order terms (polynomial). So it is really the ratio of the number of terms in your regression vs. the number of observations, which is too small.
So you need to reduce the dimensionality of your problem (aka feature reduction, aka variable selection, etc.). A very common method for this is Principal Component Analysis (PCA), and there are many others.
You should check the various posts on CV related to variable selection. You may also find this paper a very relevant one.

To add to that excellent answer, the OP is implying that AIC is used to select PCs out of order.  Data reduction using PCA is only valid if you use AIC to select $k$ when forcing the ordering of usage of PCs by selecting $PC_{1}, PC_{2}, \ldots, PC_{k}$.

Here's another excellent paper on the topic of variable selection.
for TG2 of the STRATOS initiative, Willi Sauerbrei, Aris Perperoglou, Matthias Schmid, Michal Abrahamowicz, Heiko Becher, Harald Binder, et al. “State of the Art in Selection of Variables and Functional Forms in Multivariable Analysis—Outstanding Issues.” Diagnostic and Prognostic Research 4, no. 1 (December 2020): 3, s41512-020-00074–3. https://doi.org/10.1186/s41512-020-00074-3.
